# Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<Authenticator.Retry> to Class<? extends IRetryAnalyzer>

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

I am learning selenium now-a-days, I got stuck at one point, can anyone please help me out?

While using `IRetryAnalyzer`, in my test case I use this in annotation:

```
@Test(groups= {"ErrorHandling"},retryAnalyzer=Retry.class)
```

but I am getting an error here stating:

`"Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<Authenticator.Retry> to Class<? extends IRetryAnalyzer>"`. There is a quick fix given (Add cast to 'Class<? extends IRetryAnalyzer> but when I am doing it it gives another error.

please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: A couple of tips: (1) Your question is not about "selenium-chromedriver". You should remove that tag and find some correct tags for your question. (2) You should at least explain what programming language your code snippets are from, and what API your code references like "IRetryAnalyzer" come from.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add package name before retry class in annotation
Eg: retryAnalyzer = packagename.Retry.class

Comment: Using tags helps more to visually understand your anwser, for example, the code you have posted.